# Adding Error bars from ANOVA + Tukey's posthoc in a Line Graph in R (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, line

I'm trying to add error bars from an ANOVA analysis with Tukey's post-hoc to my line graph in R using `ggplot2`. Thanks in advance, and I'm happy to post any more info that will help me solve this problem!

Here is my code so far:

```
#### ANOVA ####
aov_CW <- aov(CW ~ Subject, data = VisualAcuity)
summary(aov_CW)
model.tables(aov_CW, "means")

#### Tukey HSD post-hoc Test ####
TukeyHSD(aov_CW, conf.level = 0.95)

#### Line Plot ####

VisualAcuity$Subject <- as.factor(VisualAcuity$Subject)
VisualAcuity$Day <- as.factor(VisualAcuity$Day)
ggplot(data=VisualAcuity, aes(x=Day, y=CW, group = Subject)) +
  geom_line(size=1, aes(color = Subject)) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=21, aes(color = Subject, fill = Subject)) +
  ylim(0, max(1)) + ylab ('Visual Acuity (CW)') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = CW - se, ymax = CW + se))
```

[image: Sample data for question]

Comment: Hi Philippe, it will be much easier to help if you can provide `VisualAcuity` or a sample of it with `dput(VisualAcuity)` or `dput(VisualAcuity[1:25,])`.

Comment: Subject 1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 3; 3; 3       Day 1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3; 1; 2; 3   CW 0.42; 0.6; 0.47; 0.43; 0.4; 0.5; 0.6; 0.7; 0.47         These are some sample values from the dataset - I have it organized in 3 columns, Subject; Day, and CW.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow the structure. It's often easier to edit your original question with the data because markdown formatting is more robust in the question.

Comment: Hey Ian, thanks for the tips - I've modified the question with some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values produced by `TukeyHSD` are for pairwise comparisons, and thus can't be plotted on the graph you provided code fore.

However, here is an approach to add standard error `sd/sqrt(n)` bars with `dplyr`. Obviously you can't add error bars for 1 observation, so I expanded your dataset with some random numbers.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
VisualAcuity$Subject <- as.factor(VisualAcuity$Subject)
VisualAcuity$Day <- as.factor(VisualAcuity$Day)

VisualAcuity %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Day,Subject) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(Mean = mean(CW),std_err = sd(CW)/sqrt(n()), n = n()) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=Mean, color = Subject, group = Subject)) +
  geom_line(size=1,) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=21, aes(fill = Subject)) +
  ylim(0, max(1)) + ylab ('Visual Acuity (CW)') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - std_err, ymax = Mean + std_err))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
VisualAcuity <- structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Day = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), CW = c(0.528, 
0.56, 0.486, 0.436, 0, 0.525, 0.622, 0.6, 0.522, 0.453, 0.5, 
0.494, 0.566, 0.606, 0.56, 0.509, 0.054, 0.593, 0.645, 0.668, 
0.56, 0.51, 0.508, 0.533, 0.518, 0.502, 0.413, 0.412, 0.042, 
0.431, 0.582, 0.508, 0.435, 0.368, 0.417, 0.485)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Ian! This is perfcet!